# 'Junk after document element' error in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to practice using AJAX with jQuery, but when I am trying to call the XML file I get an error saying 'Junk after document element'. The line it is pointing to is number 3, but I don't see anything wrong with line 3.

The XML AJAX request was working when I only had the `<life>` tag in the XML file but when I added other tags it started to give me this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<life>this is text</life>
<people> This is people</people>
<h2> this is a paragraph</h2>
```

```html
<div id="ex1">
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    <p></p>
    <h4>results:</h4>
    <button id="btn">Click for AJAX</button>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button#btn").click(function() {
        let p = document.createElement('p');
        $('div#ex1').append(p);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sample.xml',
            success: function(data) {
                $('div#ex1 p:last').append(data.querySelector('h2').innerHTML);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your xml document isn't well-formed.

Comment: There should be a one root element in a xml

Comment: As above, the XML is badly formed. Fix that and your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/opstmLrp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple "root" elements in your XML... 
Try something like the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
<life>this is text</life>
<people> This is people</people>
<h2> this is a paragraph</h2>
</content>
```